# Webserver cant find its own webaddress

Tags: windows-server-2008, webserver

I got a Windows Server 2008, with 2 webapplications running on it, www.myapp.com and update.myapp.com. When Im not on my webserver, the urls works fine, but they doesnt work when my server request those urls. However, localhost works on webserver. The server can also reach other websites just fine.

Now I need www.myapp.com to be able to talk to update.myapp.com, but since my server doesnt want to talk to itself, it wont work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange. This is hacky, but I'd edit your hosts file to point those two domains to localhost (127.0.0.1).

The windows hosts file should be in :
`%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\`

There should be an example in there. Just add two lines for those two addresses.